# Excel VBA: Accessing the individual fields in a selected ListBox row

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I am trying to access the individual cells in a selected/highlighted ListBox `"lstData"` row so I can reference their values elsewhere.

When I set a watch for `Me.lstData.SelectedItem`, I get `Expression not defined in context`.  Same with `Me.lstData.SelectedIndex` and `Me.lstData.Rows(1)`.  The only thing that kind of works for me is `Me.lstData.Value`, but it ONLY returns the leftmost cell.  When I try to plug it into the `=OFFSET` function

```
=Offset(Me.lstData.Value, ,1,1)
```

to access the cell immediately to the right, I get `Expression not defined in context` again.

How can I reference the other selected cells?

Comment: Is this a form control ListBox e.g. on a UserForm? I don't see either SelectedItem or SelectedIndex as available properties/methods. I think those are .net implementations that aren't available to you.

Comment: Yes, on a UserForm. Is there any way for me to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you had a chance to review my answer below?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use `Offset` on a `ListBox` form control. The way to reference a 'cell' in a multi-column `ListBox` is by indexing the `List` property.

Here, `i` returns the *row* of the selected item, and `1` represents the second column (base 0) of the listbox:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long

With Me.ListBox1
    i = .ListIndex
    MsgBox .List(i, 1)
End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With Me.ListBox1
    .AddItem "A"
    .List(0, 1) = "Alpha"
    .AddItem "B"
    .List(1, 1) = "Beta"
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: If the ListBox has a `RowSource` property, you can always work with that range directly (i.e., to use Offset) but you can just as easily IMO index the `List` and that's probably how I would do it, unless there were compelling reasons to work with the range itself.